# Joining a column from a table that has no value

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have one table, called table A, which is a list of ID's

Table A

```
id | 
1  |
2  |
3  |
4  |
5  |
```

Then I have another table called table B, which is a list of ID's and a value

Table B

```
id | value
1  | 473
3  | 333
4  | 533
```

I want to select all the ID's from table A even if they don't have a corresponding value in table B (the non-corresponding values can be blank/null or zero), what I want is below:

```
id |
1  | 473
2  | 
3  | 333
4  | 533
5  |
```

Comment: TableA LEFT JOIN TableB

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is a [`LEFT JOIN` with `USING`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) in the join condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM   a
LEFT   JOIN b USING (id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple LEFT JOIN:

```
select a.id, b.value
from TableA a
left join TableB b
  on a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
a.ID
,b.value
FROM A as a
LEFT JOIN B as b
ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Using the LEFT JOIN here on B will provide you all of A while showing the known and unknown matches of B.

Answer (score 0):

Left join will get you what you need. You can even put a value in for the value where there is none. This could be good for reports and what not.

```
    select 
    a.id
    ,case when(b.value in ('Null', ' ')then 'No Value'
    else b.value
    end as Value

    from Table_A a

    left join Table_B b
    on B.id = A.id
```

Comment: coalesce(b.value, 'No Value') is a small, possible improvement here.